# How to pass numeric dictionary keys (formal parameter **name) to a python function?

Tags: python

When calling this function I get the error `SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression`

```
def printAlbum(**albums):
        for year in albums:
                print year, albums[year]

printAlbum(2002='by the way', 1999='californication', 2006 = 'stadium arcadium')
```

I don't have a problem calling the function with alphabetic keys.  I've tried putting quotes around the keys and replacing the `=` with `:` but that didn't fix the issue.  Can I pass numeric keys to a function?

Comment: You should definitely rethink using keyword arguments in this situation. They are not supposed to be used like this and that's why it isn't working for you

Comment: Please read my comment on nneonneo's post as to why I was even using keyword arguments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The keys of keyword args must be valid python identifiers, e.g. must not begin with digits.

Instead, pass a dict:

```
def printAlbum(albums):
        for year in albums:
                print year, albums[year]

printAlbum(
{ 2002: 'by the way', 1999: 'californication', 2006:'stadium arcadium'}
)
```

Comment: I'm not sure why anyone downvoted this answer.  It provides the correct syntax and was the only answer that made note that valid identifiers must not begin with digits.

Answer (score 0):

```
printAlbum(2002='by the way', 1999='californication', 2006 = 'stadium arcadium')
```

is illegal syntax, because the keywords have to be valid identifiers.

You must rewrite `printAlbum` to take a plain `dict`:

```
def printAlbum(albums):
    for year, album in albums.items:
        print year, album

printAlbum({2002:'by the way', 1999:'californication', 2006:'stadium arcadium'})
```

Note that having functions whose keyword arguments are *expected* to be non-identifiers is a bad idea -- in this case, there will never be a way to call the function legally using just keyword arguments.

Comment: Yeah I wanted to rewrite the function `printAlbum` to take a plain dictionary instead but this `http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#keyword-arguments` suggested an alternative method

Comment: In python 2.7, I'm getting: `TypeError: f() keywords must be strings
`

Comment: @shx2: It's a trap! (Fixed)

Comment: I did not copy your answer. I did not even read your answer, or was aware that you had posted it.

Comment: (Plus, though you can't see it, there's a deleted answer that is exactly the same as yours, and as it now transpires, mine!)